# Allow HTTP request based on URL and security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We are developing an application that uses two services deployed on AWS-ElasticBeanstalk, lets say `app1.beanstalk.com` and `app2.beanstalk.com`. `app1` exposes some internal REST APIs (`app1.beanstalk.com/intenal/reports`) and we have the requirement to make them accessible only from app2. 
It is clear to us that we can block the requests at application level but we are looking to block the even before that ..something like a firewall. Is there any AWS service that integrates with Beanstalk and allows us to allow request to a certain URLs ex `app1.beanstalk.com/intenal/*` only if the request comes from a certain security group or subnet(VPC)

Comment: I don't know of any AWS service that will do that.  The security group rules can manage access by source (IP and security group) as well as by destination port and communication type, but cannot restrict by URI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should really be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation, so...

If your REST APIs are internal use only, couldn't you simply deploy them on a different port? You could then use security groups to make that port accessible only from app2.

In other words, your main app on app1 would be running say on port 80, and you configure your internal REST APIs to run on port 8080. Then utilize security groups to restrict access to port 8080 from app2 only.

Comment: Thank you for your advice . Sounds reasonable..i`ll further investigate .